# How to use TypeORM to add new node to a node that already has children using table closure?

Tags: hierarchical-data, typeorm

I'm trying to use [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) and follow [this example](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/tree/master/sample/sample22-closure-table) to deal with hierarchical data structure the example is only about how to create a hierarchy table and read it's path but what about when already we have a node that has children and we want to add more children to I believe we should be able to push something like this:

```js
category.children.push(newCategory);
```

but category.children is empty while it has children.

Edit1:

Here is the code:

```js
async function test() {
    let connection = await createConnection(options);
    let categoryRepository = connection.getTreeRepository(Category);
    let cat = await categoryRepository.findOneById(4, {
        relations: ['children']
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cat));
    let childChildCategory1 = new Category();
    childChildCategory1.name = "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111";
    childChildCategory1.description = "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111";
    cat["__children__"].push(childChildCategory1)
    await categoryRepository.save(cat);
    let result = await categoryRepository.findDescendants(cat);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

and here is the result:
The first console.log:

```
{
    "id":4,
        "name":"Child #2 of Category #1",
            "description":"Child #2 of Category #1",
                "level":2,
                    "__children__":[
                        { "id": 5, "name": "Child #1 of Child #2 of Category #1", "description": "Child #1 of Child #2 of Category #1", "level": 3 },
                        { "id": 6, "name": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "description": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "level": 3 },
                        { "id": 7, "name": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "description": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "level": 3 }
                    ],
                        "__has_children__":true
}
```

The second console.log:

```
[
    { "id": 4, "name": "Child #2 of Category #1", "description": "Child 
    #2 of Category #1", "level": 2 },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Child #1 of Child #2 of Category #1", 
    "description": "Child #1 of Child #2 of Category #1", "level": 3 },
    { "id": 6, "name": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", 
    "description": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "level": 
    3 },
    { "id": 7, "name": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", 
    "description": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "level": 
    3 },
    { "id": 8, "name": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", 
    "description": "Child #1 of Child #1 of Category #11111", "level": 
    3 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put `{ cascadeInsert: true, cascadeUpdate: true }` options on `@TreeChildren()` decorator ? How do you load the `category` ? If you load it through `QueryBuilder`, you may forgot join the chidrens with `leftJoinAndSelect` method.

Comment: Yeah after adding the relations in the findOptions it worked though it doesn't return property `children` instead it returns `--children--`